# generating combinations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, combinations

I have a column vector x made up of 4 elements, how can i generate all the possible combinations of the values that x can take such that x*x' is less than or equal to a certain value?
note that the values of x are positive and integers.

To be more clear:
the input is the number of elements of the column vector x and the threshold, the output are the different possible combinations of the values of x respecting the fact that x*x' <=threshold 
Example: threshold is 4 and x is a 4*1 column vector.....the output is x=[0 0 0 0].[0 0 0 1],[1 1 1 1]......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works for you -

```
threshold = 4;
A = 0:threshold
A1 = allcomb(A,A,A,A)
%// Or use: A1 = combvec(A,A,A,A).' from Neural Network Toolbox
combs = A1(sum(A1.^2,2)<=threshold,:)
```

Please note that the code listed above uses [`allcomb from MATLAB File-exchange`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb/content/allcomb.m).

Output -

```
combs =
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     2
     0     0     1     0
     0     0     1     1
     0     0     2     0
     0     1     0     0
     0     1     0     1
     0     1     1     0
     0     1     1     1
     0     2     0     0
     1     0     0     0
     1     0     0     1
     1     0     1     0
     1     0     1     1
     1     1     0     0
     1     1     0     1
     1     1     1     0
     1     1     1     1
     2     0     0     0
```

Comment: Error using ==> double
Conversion to double from cell is not possible.

Comment: How can i generalize this code? I mean if the threshold is a random value and the size of x may change?

Comment: @AmiraAkra See if this throws any error - `threshold = 4;A = repmat({0:threshold},1,threshold)`? What version of MATLAB are you using? My previous cell based approach was a generalized code, but I am suspecting that you are using some old version of MATLAB that was causing the error that you saw earlier.

Comment: I am using 7.10.0(R2010a)....and no the error was generated by -A1 = combvec(A,A,A,A).' -

Comment: @AmiraAkra Any error with `threshold = 4;A = repmat({0:threshold},1,threshold)`?

Comment: @AmiraAkra After that step, try `allcomb(A{:})` and see if it throws any error.

Comment: If I have 4 variables x1,x2,x3 and x4 and i want to generate all the possible combinations such that the sum of xi*xi' (i is either 1,2,3 and 4) is less than a threshhold....is it enough to use the code written above in a 4 iteration loop?

Comment: @AmiraAkra `xi*xi'` would be a scalar right? So, `sum of xi*xi'` doesn't make sense.

Comment: by sum xi*xi' i mean (x1*x1' + x2*x2'...) and yes it would be scalar

Comment: @AmiraAkra And `x1` is a 4 element column vector? Similarly `x2`, `x3` and `x4`  are each 4 element column vectors?

Comment: yes like the scenario described in the main question

Comment: @AmiraAkra That might need a lot of changes with the existing code, so I would suggest posting a new question. Good luck!